# Test for same coefficients with different estimation approaches

Tags: hypothesis-testing, estimation

I'm estimating coefficients $w_1,\dots, w_d$ with different approaches (for example with ML and with leave one out CV) a few times. Now I'd like to test if the coefficients are the same, but I dont know an appropriate test. So I'd like to test, if $w_1=w_1 \quad \& \quad w_2=w_2 ...$

Has someone a recommendation?

Comment: If it's the same model, then *a fortiori* the coefficients are the same!  Any differences between the estimates produced by the two procedures are functions of the procedures.  The idea of "testing" doesn't seem to apply.

Answer (score 0):

Partially answered in comments:

If it's the same model, then a fortiori the coefficients are the same! Any differences between the estimates produced by the two procedures are functions of the procedures. The idea of "testing" doesn't seem to apply. – whuber

What you could look into is *comparison* of the estimation procedures, either theoretically (calculating bias, variance, ...) or by simulation.